# Compass sprite background color

Tags: background, sprite, compass-sass, sass

Can compass generate a sprite with a solid background?

I mean without alpha channel.

I want the white background for reducing a file size.

[See what I want](http://minus.com/lb1IZXN3fe4aKq)

Comment: Why do you have so much whitespace in a first place?

Comment: I use the additional spacing: 
$sprite: sprite-map('img/sprite/*.png', $position: 0%, $spacing: 30px, $repeat: no-repeat);

Comment: Because html tag height is bigger than sprite item and without spacing next one appears in the same tag

Comment: illustration http://minus.com/ln2ItCmW4lChx

Comment: Couldn't you just set the background color to white as well?

Comment: Do you mean the sprite params? No, the compass sprite has not such param.

Answer (score 1):

What I do is set the sprite and then the background color, like so:

```
.i-facebook {
   @include home-sprite(i-facebook, false, 20px, 20px);
   background-color: $blue;
}
```

And what you will get is: http://d.pr/i/8yme

*Note: I am using 20px spacing on my sprite.*

*I would be interested if there is a better way to do it.*

Comment: It is the obvious answer, but not for this question. It doesn't reduce a sprite file size.